# How to get the Shop base URL in prestashop to use in admin tab tpl files?

Tags: prestashop

I created a module, and hook using displayAdminProductsExtra to displayed in admin panel.I want to use the base_url smarty variable in back end tpl files.I searched and came to known that base_url is only for front end tpl files. How to get the base url and use in back end tpl files? any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you just need base directory use `__PS_BASE_URI__` for complete URL you can use

```
_PS_BASE_URL_.__PS_BASE_URI__
```

Comment: Good answer i was looking for that too, works like a charm :)

Comment: Just in case somebody would found this searching for *absolute* (server) path to home directory => use `_PS_ROOT_DIR_` (it would give you *something like* `/var/www/yourClientName/web/shopDirectory`

Answer (score 5):

```
Context::getContext()->shop->getBaseURL(true);
```

Answer (score 4):

Put this into your template file (`*.tpl`)

```
{$base_dir}
```

Example:

```
<a href="{$base_dir}content/6-about-us">About Us</span></a>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. A little more explanation might help out the fellow programmers to understand how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Front-end:

If you wishing to access site base url in front-end file, Use:

```
{$base_dir}
```

Admin Panel:

If you wishing to use site base url in admin module files, Use:

```
Tools::getHttpHost(true).__PS_BASE_URI__
```